# Finding the current user authenticated by basic auth (Apache)

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, perl, cgi

When you log in through a basic auth page, is the username you authenticated as stored anywhere (on the server or client machine), maybe in an environment variable?

**Background**: I have a common web administration page for an e-mail server and I'd like to know who is doing what. When a user successfully logs in via basic auth, I somehow want to be able to identify them and log their actions. So each time a request is submitted, I can write to a log file. The basic format would be:

```
$username ran a $function against $useraccount
```

so if a user changed someone's permissions, eg:

```
Admin-Bob ran a permission change against User-Scott
```

So if errors occur, I can easily trace back in the log file what actions lead to the cause. I tried checking the `%ENV` hash to no avail, any Ideas?

I don't really want to get into PHP-like sessions, because that would mean scrapping my basic auth, which gives me a fine degree of control already. If I have to code something with sessions, I'd need to implement a system to block users after maximum tries and so on, which I don't really want to code. I think this is better geared towards serverfault because it pertains to Apache moreso than the programming language. Sessions can be done in a myriad of languages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The username will be available in the environment variable `REMOTE_USER`.

This works for nearly every authentication method, should you ever start using digest or maybe even kerberos authentication.

Comment: Cheers, works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Shtééf already mentioned `$ENV{'REMOTE_USER'}`, but if you're using CGI.pm, it's also returned by the `remote_user()` function.

```
my $cgi = CGI->new();
print $cgi->remote_user(); # Prints user name
```

Answer (score 0):

Its actually a server variable, not environment.

PHP_AUTH_USER and AUTH_USER should both work.

Comment: In CGI it _is_ an environment variable. Welcome to the "PHP is not everything" world.